# Zippered travel sheets that open flat with a pillow insert that are machine-washable?

Tags: gear, sleeping

I can't seem to find a sheet with all the qualities listed above...either they are handwash only or they only open on one side halfway etc.  I'm looking "hotel" style sheets & not the "mummy" type. So, are there any travel sheets that are super-light; machine washable; opens flat (can be used open or zippered); with a place to put your own pillow or protect one from a dirty one; & uses zippers?

I searched and searched but nothing to be found...the Sea to Summit stuff is okay but they don't open flat from what I have read.

Comment: What's the "mummy" type?

Comment: What about [these](http://www.longroad.com/products/Travel-Sheets.html)? Appears to fully unzip, rectangular, pillow pocket, different types of material available...

Comment: @Mark Mayo: those "liners" used in sleeping bags...shaped like a mummy instead if rectangular...

Comment: @MarkMayo: "Mummy" is often used to describe one of two types of sleeping bag, the type that wraps the shoulders and has an attached hood for the head. I forget the name for the other type which just ends with a flat opening at the shoulders.

Comment: (facepalm) of course. When I read 'mummy' I was thinking like 'mother' and was at a loss as to what type that would be.

Comment: @MarkMayo, should the title be edited to be more canonical? i.e., travellers with allergies or avoiding unsanitary bedding? Will net searchers find it currently?

Comment: @GayotFow he's very specific about the type, so I'm not sure :/

Answer (score 3):

These are popular in Germany and are available in the retail markets there.  I used the Google search term "Reißverschluss Reise Bettwäsche" which roughly translates to 'bed sheets for travel that close with a zipper'.  I also used "Hausstaubmilben-Allergiker" (house dust allergy) with less conclusive results.

From a *canonical* point of view, the objective in using these sheets is to insulate yourself from the sheets and covers provided by the hotel (or host) such that your contact is limited to your own bedding and to thereby enjoy a more hygienic sleep.  They would be indispensable for tropical or dusty venues and a solid travel tip for almost anywhere else. The image below demonstrates how they work...

[image]

The red line portrays a cross-sectional view of how the sheet is meant to be used.  There is a zipper on the side so that all contact with the bed and bedding is avoided.

I looked at the various offerings in the market and selected a vendor that offered the closest product to what you are looking for.  I then sent them an email in German asking if they were able to handle an English speaking customer and provide this product by telephone or on-line ordering.

They answered my email promptly and confirmed they are happy to receive your English enquiries (by telephone or by email) and ship to you.  The large sheet is 39 Euro plus shipping if you are outside of Germany.  I forgot to ask if they will  give VAT relief for non-EEA customers so it's something you can take up when you enquire.

Note for your specific requirements:  this product is machine washable and tumble dried.

Their email is  info@allergika.de and their site is at http://www.allergika.de/Produkte/Hausstaubmilben%20Allergie/ALLERGIKA%20Travel%20Reiseschlafsack.html

To be fair, there is another vendor at http://www.bettwaren-shop.de/ offering virtually the same product at a comparable price.  There's another at vendor at http://www.allergiker-shop-alfda.de/Allergiker-Bettwaesche-Encasing/ which offers a seemingly higher quality product, including a pillow case (at substantially higher prices).

Comment: Are you the author of the image?

Comment: @yo' yes.  Isn't it wonderful? It's added to the public domain if you want to republish it.

Comment: Cool! I especially like the colour of the blanked. It digs out some French memories :D

Answer (score 2):

How does [the CT-22C (With Zipper) from Longroad](http://www.longroad.com/products/Travel-Sheets.html) sound? According to the description it can be used both flat and zippered, is machine washable since it's 100% cotton, and is lightweight at ∼ 500g. I am not sure it has a pillow pocket though, as the website isn't very clear. Might be worth [contacting them](http://www.longroad.com/pages/Contact-Us.html).

Below is a screenshot from the [aforementioned Longroad website](http://www.longroad.com/products/Travel-Sheets.html):
[image]