# Reasonably priced hotel. NYC UWS or UES

Tags: hotels

We are looking for a reasonably($200-250) priced hotel. Upper west-side or upper east-side. My wife is freaked out about bedbugs. Any suggestions.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38853/zippered-travel-sheets-that-open-flat-with-a-pillow-insert-that-are-machine-wash

Comment: The Lucerne (240), Day's Inn Hotel (130)

Comment: So it's written down somewhere: take reviews online seriously. Some of the Internet sites--ones I used myself, not scams--list derelict flophouses.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the major booking sites?  That's where you'll find the exact prices.  There's also airbnb.

I've stayed in NYC Hotels dozens of times and never seen a bedbug.  They take it very seriously.

Comment: Ambiguous pronoun "They" :)